# how to avoid line breaks between text and lists

Tags: html, line-breaks

i have the following code on a web page:

```
 Team:
        <ul class="checkboxTree[0] checkboxTree" id="tree2">

. . . . .
```

the ul list shows up a line below the Text "Team".  How can i get it to show up directly to the right of the team and not have any line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unordered list is a block-level element.

I'd need more information to give you good advice, but the simplest way is a CSS rule:

```
#tree2 { display: inline }
```

or

```
#tree2 { display: inline-block }
```

See [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) for the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by using css like `display`, or `float`.
Example:

```
.checkboxTree
{
float: left;
}
```

For more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: I think you need to float the ul and "Team" for that to work?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's just that `ul` may have a large margin, so you would need `.checkboxTree { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px }` or similar.

Comment: @Mikel: Please try it, not just guess. Default display for `ul` is `block` so it will break the like even if you set the `margin` is `zero`. To prevent that, you must change the `display` attribute or using `float` or somethings else that I don't know yet. And I try myself, `margin` is not enough to fix this.

Comment: I meant that after doing float or display inline, you also need to reduce the top margin, or else it will still appear to be lower than "Team".